# String.init(stringInterpolation:) with an array of strings

Tags: arrays, swift, string, string-interpolation, swift5

I was reading over some resources about Swift 5's String Interpolation and was trying it out in a Playground. I successfully combined two separate `String`s but I am confused about how to combine an `Array` of `String`s.
Here's what I did ...

```
String(stringInterpolation: {
    let name = String()
    var combo = String.StringInterpolation(literalCapacity: 7, interpolationCount: 1)
    combo.appendLiteral("Sting One, ")
    combo.appendInterpolation(name)
    combo.appendLiteral("String Two")

    print(combo)
    return combo
}())
```

How would you do something like this with an `Array` of `String`s?

Comment: Unclear what the point of the question is. What array are we talking about? What’s the proposed input and desired output? What’s the point of using `String.StringInterpolation` directly here?

Comment: Any array will do. I'm just trying to figure out how to combine `Strings` from the same `Array`, so the output is one long `String`.

Comment: Why do you need interpolation for that? Just `join` the array (call `joined`) directly.

Comment: But then you can use `String(describing:)` to perform the conversion to a string representation. — However, I would urge you to add all this to the _question_; as I said, as it stands it is unclear what the point is, and the title “with an array of strings” would seem to be outright wrong. It might even be good just to show the actual JSON. There may be a much simpler way; this could well be an x-y question.

Answer (score 1):

It’s unclear what this is supposed to have to do with interpolation. Perhaps there’s a misunderstanding of what string interpolation is? If the goal is to join an array of strings into a single comma-separated string, just go ahead and join the array of strings into a single string:

```
let arr = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"]
let s = arr.joined(separator: ", ")
s  // "Manny, Moe, Jack”
```

If the point is that the array element type is unknown but is string-representable, map thru `String(describing:)` as you go:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let s = arr.map{String(describing:$0)}.joined(separator: ", ")
s  // "1, 2, 3”
```